# Taking ownership from Root

Tags: partitioning, ownership

With a fresh installation and beiing new to the Linux world ,I created a new partition ext4 with gparted to put the Timeshift files , How can i take the ownership back from root under Linux MInt 19.3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sudo chown -R $USER /path/to/directory` to use [chown](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/chown.1.html) with the -R flag to change the ownership of the folder and everything within it from root to USER. To change the rights with [chmod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/chmod.1posix.html), do `sudo chmod -R RW /path/to/directory`